# How to set android:scaleType to a viewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scaletype

I want to set android:scaleType attribute to a viewpager to scale the images of a viewpager. But i cannot find the attribute within ViewPager. Is there any other similar attribute which I can use. I even tried a third party viewpager, but didnt work. Pls help and thanks in advance.

Comment: add it to the imageview?

Comment: ViewPager is mandatory in my app.

Comment: also the ImageView I think

Comment: I cannot use ImageView so I am using ViewPager. ImageView doesnt serve my purpose for scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave your `ViewPager` as is.
Build a custom adapter (extending `PagerAdapter`) for your `ViewPager`, where you inflate a certain view for every position.
This certain view will hold an ImageView, and you'll pass your image to this `ImageView` in the adapter's following method:

```
@Override
public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item_with_image, container, false);
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_image_view)).setImageResource(mImages[position]);

    container.addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}
```

And this might be your adapter's constructor with the needed variables:

```
LayoutInflater mInflater;
private static final int[] mImages;
static {
    mImages = new int[]{
            R.drawable.img1,
            R.drawable.img2,
            R.drawable.img3,
            R.drawable.img4,
            R.drawable.img5,
    };
}

public MyViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageView and set android:scaleType there. And for ViewPager you should have your PagerAdapter and inflate xml with ImageView

Comment: But I am using third party viewpager [https://github.com/imbryk/LoopingViewPager] which doesnt have PagerAdapter.

Comment: And what you want to achieve in the end and for this reason you can not use the standard ViewPager?

Comment: I want infinite looping viewpager as well as the images of the viewpager should scale the whole available view.

Comment: In your xml you can set width = match_parent and height = match_parent, android:scaleType = "centerCrop" on ImageView and as parent use LinearLayout(for example)